# Каким образом я могу редактировать изображение на node.js?

Tags: node.js, обработка-изображений, discord-api

Делаю бота для Discord сервера. Так же есть такое изображение:[image]
Изображение(фон) находится в одной папке с ботом, остальные данные я получаю из кода.

Требуется разместить на фоне этого изображение:

1. Другую картинку
2. Некий текст

Каким образом я могу это сделать? Заранее спасибо за помощь)